# According to Arminians, why do they find Calvinism distasteful or inaccurate?

Tags: reformed-theology, free-will, predestination, arminianism, unconditional-election

R.C. Sproul, a Reformed thinker said in his book “Chosen by God” that: “Jimmy Swaggart has made it clear that he considers the Reformed view a demonic heresy.” (Page 7)

Obviously, disagreements can exist in a ***healthy manner*** with respect to Soteriological beliefs…

**Q: Why do some **arminians** think that the reformed view is as distasteful to be called demonic or heresy?**

Comment: Depicting other legitimately held theological perspectives should ever be called a demonic heresy, so I won't offer this as an answer. But the simple explanation for the moral revulsion is that for me, if God predestines some to be saved, he implicitly chooses others to spend eternity in hell. Furthermore, this invalidates the God-imaging value of free will, which is one of the best explanations for why there is SO much suffering and pain in this world. Highly charged, moral problems that go to the heart of what it means to be human and for God to be good, hence overly charged condemnation.

Comment: @ninthamigo I appreciate the response here from you.  Have you ever considered that Genesis 1:26-27 doesn’t have any exegetical grounds for asserting “free will”?  Where in Scripture does it say we have “free will”?  We make choices that are free, yes, but our will is limited.  Jesus responded about “free will” in a sense: “Then Pilate said to Him, “Are You not speaking to me? Do You not know that I have power to crucify You, and power to release You?” Jesus answered, “You could have no power at all against Me unless it had been given you from above…”
John 19:10-11 {our power/will is limited.

Comment: Free-will thinking is baked into the very idea of choice and responsibility. Therefore, every choice God presents includes a (yes limited) freedom to choose one or another path forward. This is the nature of the uncorrupted will of Adam and Eve in the garden when commanded by God not to eat of the fruit. If God genuinely wanted them not to eat of it, they could not have done so if they had wanted, or, at least, they never would have wanted to. But his desire to have genuine, voluntary relationship trumped this, which left open the choice which God knew would lead to disobedience.

Comment: You note John 19:10-11, but this is exactly the dehumanizing way of thinking that is so problematic in Calvinism. In an effort to affirm God's providence, you rush right past the realness of Pilate's sinful choice to keep his job and kill the Lord of Glory. Of course he could not have done so if in a sense God's power did not allow for that free choice, but then we are confronted by the realization that God created a world and chooses to support a world full of rebels, in order that real choice is possible.

Comment: You also note there is no 'free will' in Gen. 1. But God is free, and if we are reflection of him, them we must reflect his freedom (within the limitations of any mirror). Furthermore, consider God's warning to Cain even after the fall which speaks of an either or regarding his desire to kill his brother in Genesis 4:7. Ultimately, as an Arminian, Calvinist conceptions of freedom are dehumanizing, and consequently unglorifying to God. What do you consider to be 'free will' and it's purpose for God and humans?

Comment: @ninthamigo You said “In an effort to affirm God's providence, you rush right past the realness of Pilate's sinful choice to keep his job and kill the Lord of Glory. Of course he could not have done so if in a sense God's power did not allow for that free choice…”.  I never rushed passed Pilates choice, in fact God intended Jesus to die: “Acts 4:27-28 shows God was in fact behind Christ’s death.  Acts 2:22-24 show God delivered Jesus over to death(Providence) & they{Men of Israel} put Jesus to death by their wicked hands(human responsibility).  They wanted to kill Jesus out of their own hearts

Comment: But from my perspective, you sound like you are making human choices merely parts of God's choice. Evil is an illusion, as is responsibility, justice, love, all this is part of a staged play whose parts we are living out, but which God wrote long ago. Ultimately, I don't think this question gets beyond the most basic, Calvinism vs Arminianism, who is right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Ultimately, this is what people like Jimmy Swaggart are getting at. [Do Calvinists believe that God is the author of evil?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12015/do-calvinists-believe-that-god-is-the-author-of-evil)

Comment: @ninthamigo I will say, I forgot to reply to this comment.  No, I’m not looking for an answer to that question, I’m asking rather “Why do some Arminian’s insist that Calvinism is demonic?”

Answer (score 2):

### Calvinism is not a demonic lie, but...

I was really hoping this question would disappear because it is not edifying or helpful to dwell on particular pieces of hurtful rhetoric which have been volleyed back and forth between Calvinists and Arminians. Since it instead seems to be picking up steam, and instead engendering foundationless caricatures of Arminianism, I will attempt to answer it to the best of my ability.

**1. Calvinism is not a demonic lie**

Just as the oft-repeated claim of Calvinists that Arminianism is really just the heresy of Pelagianism repackaged, Jimmy Swaggart is wrong if he claims that Calvinism and especially Calvinists are servants of the devil. This is both because **(a)** most of the positive reasons for believing Calvinism are grounded in scripture and orthodox Christian history, and **(b)** many Calvinists do not consciously hold to the dangerous implications of their theology which might cause an outsider to label it demonic. Both these principles are made clear by thoughtful theologians on both sides of this debate.

**2. But...**

For those incapable of passing off certain horrifying logical implications of predestination, determinism, and limited atonement as unknowable mysteries, and for those unwilling to ignore clear biblical warrants against things like limited atonement (which is why *many* Calvinists are 4-pointers), to believe in Calvinism would make God into some form of unrecognizable monster. See what Roger Olsen writes in the conclusion of his book *Against Calvinism*:

> But the greatest conundrum of them all has to do with God’s character.
> Nearly all Calvinists confess that God is the standard of moral
> goodness, the source of all values, the perfectly loving source of
> love. Then they also confess that God ordains, designs, controls, and
> renders certain the most egregious evil acts such as the kidnapping,
> rape, and murder of a small child and the genocidal slaughter of
> hundreds of thousands in Rwanda. They confess that God “sees to it”
> that humans sin, as with the fall of Adam and eve. And they confess
> that all salvation is absolutely God’s doing and not at all dependent
> on free will decisions of people (monergism), and that God only saves
> some when he could save all—assuring that some large portion of
> humanity will spend eternity in hell when he could save them from
> it...For me, and most non-Calvinists, nothing is more important to
> preserve, protect, and promote than the good name of God—God’s
> reputation based on his good character. Insofar as Calvinism
> undermines that, I cannot live with its conundrums because they all
> ultimately injure God’s reputation—making it difficult to tell the
> difference between God and the devil.

He goes on to point out a distinction between persons and beliefs which is why neither he, nor I believe Calvinists are devil worshippers, but hopefully this makes the connection between our moral revulsion towards Calvinism's implications clearer.

> Some readers may question the sincerity of my pledge or the success of
> my effort to write about Calvinism with an irenic Spirit. I ask,
> however, that you keep clearly in mind the difference between
> *persons* and *beliefs*.

Comment: I appreciate your time & effort to help me understand the counter view better, +1

Comment: I recommend the book and the corresponding *Against Arminianism* if you want to do a deeper dive into the issues.

Comment: I’ve read “For Calvinism” before, & I’ve heard of “Against Arminianism” too, I will get it asap.  (Financial troubles atm)

Comment: oh, actually that's the one I'm thinking of, "Against Calvinism" and "For Calvinism" come as a set

Answer (score 0):

A danger with this important question is that the issue of 'free will' might be raised, like a red flag to a bull, and arguments start. Although that is certainly involved in disagreements between Arminians and Calvinists, there's more to it than that. Indeed, without a grasp of the historical issues raised around 1610, the question can hardly be answered.

Here is an explanatory quotation which I am confident Arminians will agree is fair comment on how what came to be an irreconcilable rift began.

> "We must take our starting point in Holland in the year 1610. James
> Arminius, a Dutch professor, had just died and his teaching had been
> formulated into five main points of doctrine by his followers - known
> as Arminians. Up to this point, the churches of Holland, in common
> with the other major Protestant churches of Europe, had subscribed to
> the Belgic and Heidelberg Confessions of Faith, which were both set
> squarely on Reformation teachings. The Arminians wanted to change this
> position, however, and they presented their five points in the form of
> a Remonstrance - or protest - to the Dutch Parliament.
>
> *1. Free will, or human ability.* This taught that man, although affected by the Fall, was not totally incapable of choosing spiritual
> good, and was able to exercise faith in God in order to receive the
> gospel and thus bring himself into possession of salvation.
>
> *2. Conditional election.* This taught that God laid His hands upon those individuals who, He knew - or foresaw - would respond to the
> gospel. God elected those that He saw would want to be saved of their
> own free will and in their natural fallen state - which was, of
> course, according to the first point of Arminianism, not completely
> fallen anyway.
>
> *3. Universal redemption, or general atonement.* This taught that Christ died to save all men; but only in a *potential* fashion.
> Christ's death enabled God to pardon sinners, but only on condition
> that they believed.
>
> *4. The work of the Holy Spirit in regeneration limited by the human will.* This taught that the Holy Spirit, as He began to work to bring
> a person to Christ, could be effectually resisted and His purposes
> frustrated. He could not impart life unless the sinner was willing to
> have this life imparted.
>
> *5. Falling from grace.* This taught that a saved man could fall finally from salvation. It is, of course, the logical and natural
> outcome of the system. If man must take the initiative in his
> salvation, he must retain responsibility for the final outcome. (*The Five
> Points of Calvinism* p7, W.J. Seaton, The Banner of Truth Trust)

In 1618 a National Synod of the church met in Dort to examine those teachings in light of scripture. It sat for 154 sessions over seven months. The outcome was inability to reconcile the Arminian viewpoint with what they saw in the scriptures. This led to a reaffirmation of the Protestant view on those matters. Although John Calvin had been dead for 50 years, his theology was used to form what has come to be known as 'TULIP' - an acrostic standing for:

T - Total depravity (= total inability)

U - Unconditional Election

L - Limited Atonement (= particular redemption)

I - Irresistible Calling

P - Perseverance of the Saints

Without going into arguments about how TULIP is incompatible with those 5 Arminian points, I will simply say that it is perfectly obvious that both theologies cannot be correct. If one system is correct, the other is wrong - totally wrong. The various points stand or fall together. This is one of those matters where there can be no mixing or matching to come up with a patchwork quilt incorporating both sets of views, or some from one stitched to some from the other.

Arminianism clashes head on with the Calvinistic stance. That might be why Jimmy Swaggart is reported as saying the Reformed view is "a demonic heresy". **Both stances cannot be correct. Arminians have taken a firm stand which opposes the Reformed (Calvinistic) stand. This was established after 154 sessions over seven months in 1618. Nothing has changed since then**, except, perhaps, some taking more entrenched stances so that they publicly attack Calvinism in a vitriolic manner.

As someone who sees spiritual dangers with the Arminian view, I would simply say that it has corrupted the biblical gospel of Jesus Christ, which is why I am not an Arminian. For the same reason, that is why I am not a supporter of other denominations that have also not stuck faithfully to the biblical gospel. I had to leave one denomination after discovering it was not preaching the Christ, nor the gospel, of scripture. That was when I became a Christian - when I woke up to just who the Christ, and the gospel, of scripture is. But I'm not here to argue about that. I'm just here to answer your question by pointing to what particular beliefs  Arminianism was founded on, and that Calvinism examined them in light of scripture and could not agree with them.

Comment: Very disappointing. You may genuinely be trying your best to represent Arminianism, but -1 for doing so with the words of a Calvinist that almost entirely mispresent the 1610 Synod of Dort. I encourage you to read the actual words of that statement which AT MINIMUM **deny** 'human ability' and withhold an opinion on 'falling from grace'. https://www.theopedia.com/five-articles-of-remonstrance

Comment: @Anne Interesting survey.  There is a lot more for me to learn of course.

Comment: Very well balanced. True to history and true to the clear, unbiased reading of the scripture. Up-voted +1.

Comment: I meant Articles of Remonstrance, but have you even read it? @NigelJ it directly contradicts several of these supposed 'fair' representations of Arminianism that purport to summarize it?

Comment: @ninthamigo I have looked at your link to the Articles of Remonstrance and find them deeply unconvincing and truly superficial, merely associating (not expounding) irrelevant scriptures which are inappropriate to the subject being remonstrated.

Comment: @NigelJ I don't think you understand my point. I don't care what you think of them, they make up the actual document which defines Arminianism as opposed to the false caricature of *them* which Seaton gives above. If you accept a Calvinist oversimplification as better representing Arminianism than the founding Arminian document, that's like believing the Quran's interpretation of the bible is more biblical that the bible is itself.